# Error on RoR app, when I go to the new page that I created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**PROBLEM SOLVED! In my case the problem was the node version, too new. I downgraded the version and it works!**

---

I am totally new to RoR and I have a problem that I have not been able to solve.
I'm using **Rails 6.1.7.3** and **Ruby 3.0.6p216**
When I enter the new url that I create, it returns the following error:

> **Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Pages#home**
>
> Webpacker can't find application.js in C:/Users/...n. Possible causes:
> You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
> unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
> webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
> You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
> Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
> Your manifest contains:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %><%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

My package.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "first-project",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
         "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
         "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
         "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
         "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
         "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
         "webpack": "4.46.0",
         "webpack-cli": "3.3.12"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack-dev-server": "3"
    }
}
```

I have tried reinstalling some gems, changing versions of Ruby and Rails, and reinstalling webpacker as well. But the error continues.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else to try?  Thank you in advance

Comment: since you're new to Ruby on Rails, I recommend you start with version 7, because Webpacker is no longer the default javascript packaging scheme. It uses esbuild instead. Better to start with that than try to understand webpacker and then learn something different later.

Comment: I understand, maybe I should, it's just that the course I took had those versions and from what I had understood, it was very likely that the versions would collide if I changed them. But I should give it a try. Any version suggestions?

Comment: rails 7.0.5 released May 24

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the assets might not be compiled properly.
try to compile using `bundle exec rails webpacker:compile`

Comment: I've tried to run that comand and I've got the following error


`Compiling...
Compilation failed:
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods' imported from C:\Users\laura\OneDrive\Escritorio\first-project-ror\first-project\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js`

Answer (score 0):

Got an error message running `bin/webpack-dev-server --help` related to a missing dependency: `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`.

Install as devDependencies:

- @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods
- @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object

after that, got no problem.